# Postfix server only attempts to connect on (blocked) port 25, not 587 as set in config

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, dovecot

I have just finished the setup of a postfix/dovecot mail server installation, running on GCP Compute Engine.

Receiving email works as intended, but I have been having difficulty with sending mail. It is my understanding that GCP block port 25, and so I have made changes to my configuration to attempt to run over 587 instead.

However, despite running `postfix reload`, `systemctl restart dovecot` and `reboot`, the changes don't seem to take effect, postfix still appears to be trying to communicate over port 25, as seen below.

```
Mar  1 10:44:45 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1942]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c07::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar  1 10:45:15 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1942]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[172.217.214.27]:25: Connection timed out
Mar  1 10:45:45 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1942]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.77.27]:25: Connection timed out
Mar  1 10:45:45 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1942]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4023:401::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar  1 10:45:45 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1942]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c08::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Mar  1 10:45:45 ubuntu postfix/smtp[1942]: 74407410F1: to=<my@email>, relay=none, delay=5266, delays=5206/0.02/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c08::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

I am able to `telnet` into 587 on my server and receive the banners I expect, it just seems like the mail server isn't trying to use 587. As you can see in the log above, every time it's attempting to connect it's doing it over :25.

Any guidance that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated, but I am trying to avoid using a relay if at all possible.

My master config is below.

**master.cf**

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
587       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
```

Answer (score 1):

In `main.cf` for your Postfix installation, make sure you have a line similar to this:

`relayhost = [relayserver.somedomain.com]:587`

This naturally requires that you have a relay host to actually use in this way. I imagine Google does allow you to relay outbound mail via their mail service.

Comment: Thanks Mikael. I've gone with this approach for now (SendGrid) but ideally I'd like to be able to run my mail server without a relay host. Do you know if that's possible with this configuration?

Comment: If you host your server with a provider that allows outbound mail without requiring it to be relayed, then yes. You can’t expect the receiving end to accept inbound mail on a non-standard port, though: Port 587 is for mail submission, not for general SMTP traffic.